# Streaming video with RTSP

Tags: ios, video, networking, streaming, rtsp

I have an iOS app that creates an RTSP url for streaming video, then I can play the video in VLC with that URL.

When I am on the same wifi network as my computer that is running the VLC my ip address is: **rtsp://192.168.0.134/**

And that url plays the video stream just fine.

When I switch wifi networks, my URL changes to **rtsp://172.20.10.2/**

But my video won't stream now that I am on a different wifi network.

Why does the video stream when the phone and VLC are on the same wifi network, but doesn't work when the phone is on a different wifi network?

Comment: Consider that RTP/RTSP ports may be blocked by the firewall, this is one of the reasons why HTTP based streaming is so awesome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Many WiFi networks act simply as access points with no cooperation between other access points - unlike a corporate Wifi or airport wifi where the individual access points all co-operate via a controller and you can roam.

Given that you are on two different WiFi networks, each with its own private addressing range (you can tell this from the IP addresses) then your upstream network would need to have a a method to map addresses from one network to another.

If both WiFi networks are your own, then the usual way to address this is to have the Wifi networks ask the upstream network for the their address and for the range of addresses they should offer.

**Update**

Assuming you want to stream from your iOS device from any network to your player, the usual way to do this is via a streaming server.

The flow is:

> iOS device ---> Streaming Server ---> Device with Player

The iOS device needs a URL or IP address for the streaming server that is publicly available if you want it to work across networks. The iOS device then sends the stream to the server which may or may not repackage it and may also store it so it is available later or with a 'time shift'. The player connects to the streaming server to access the stream and plays it from there.

There is an example here which uses a common web player and a common streaming engine, which may help point you in the right direction and explain some of the common steps:

- https://www.jwplayer.com/blog/how-to-stream-live-video-from-your-iphone-to-the-jw-player/

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm not following your answer... I will not know beforehand what wifi networks are going to be used, since this is in an iOS app.  So what you are saying is that whenever I play the video, I will need to get the IP address the video player is on and the IP address from the rtsp url and make some type of code for the video player to map the urls to be able to communicate with each other?

Comment: @MSU_Bulldog - I've updated the answer to show a more general use case that is not tied to private networks.